# How to block one specific XHR request in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

In the google chrome dev tools, I would like to block a specific XHR from loading. The problem is there are many XHR with the same name and loaded from the same url, but I only want to block one.

I have already searched many articles about blocking XHR, but all of them block XHR by blocking a URL.

I want to only block one, but when I block the source url, all of them got blocked.

Is it possible to only block a specific XHR, if yes, how to block it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The URL of all the XHR requests is the exact same?

Comment: yeah, all of them have the same name with the same url source

Comment: So you request `example.json` 5 times and you only want to block it the 3rd time that it’s requested?

Comment: yeah the website requested `example.custom` like 5 times and i only want to block one of the requests.